# Calculated field mysteriously changing and losing the field reference for a SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I am using the following calculation in a SharePoint List:  `=IF([Modified]+10<=TODAY(),"Y","N")`.  I use the answer to drive some conditional formatting of the item.  It works perfectly.

The problem is that I will periodically see where the formatting doesn't show up when it should.  I will check the calculation and see that it has changed to:  `=IF(Modified+10<=TODAY(),"Y","N")`.  You can see that it dropped the "[ ]" that wrap the Modified field.  As soon as I add them back, it works.

I cannot figure out why this happens.

Thoughts?

Comment: UPDATE:  I just discovered that if I do a simple filter on a column wihtin the list, I lose the "[ ]" in the formula.  However, the formatting sticks for any items that meet the criteria at that moment.  New entries or updates to current entries don't get the formatting.  :-/

Comment: I posted this on another tech forum and was provided the following article which helped put the issue into perspective.  http://dalecox99.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-row-id-value-in-calculated-column.html